How to prove that we can form at least one n-sided convex polygon (not necessarily regular) using the grid points on an infinite uniform grid plane?
This problem was derived from an application of a computer version algorithm.
Given a uniform grid plane, can we always find at least one n-sided convex polygon (not necessarily regular) with the grid points as the vertices for any integer n>=3?
Or:
If $\forall n\in \{n|n\in \mathbb{Z}^+,n\ge 3\}$, define
$$\begin{split}
\mathbf{V}_n=\{&((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),\ldots,(x_n,y_n))|\\
&((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),\ldots,(x_n,y_n))\in (\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z})^n,\\
&\forall i,j \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}, i\ne j, (x_i,y_i)\ne (x_j,y_j)\}
\end{split}$$.
Is it $\forall n\in \{n|n\in \mathbb{Z}^+,n\ge 3\}$:$\exists ((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),\ldots,(x_n,y_n))\in \mathbf{V}_n$:$(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),\ldots,(x_n,y_n)$ can form a convex polygon (not necessarily regular)?
I think it may be possible, but how to give out rigorous proof? I have thought about it carefully, but I don't know the idea or direction of the proof.
Thanks in advance.

Are you asking whether you can construct any regular polygon using only points with integer coordinates? It's not possible to construct an equilateral triangle on grid points. But it is trivially possible to construct an irregular $n$-gon for any $n$.

@ChrisLewis Thanks for your comments. I've modified my problems to be more precise.

What have you tried so far? How many lattice points lie on a circle centred at the origin with radius $65$? Can you see how that would help? And how did I come up with $65$?

@YvesDaoust Thanks. I've modified it.

Your use of the quantifier $\exists$ is wrong. You probably meant "for all $n\ge 3$ exists a list of points ..."

@jjagmath You are right. I'm going to correct it.

@YvesDaoust Thanks. I've modified my statement following your suggestion. Yours is correct and more concise.
